# Mongo dump for a collection on a specific date

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I want to take the backup of a specific collection for a specific date.

My use case is :
I have to take the backup of data that are older than 90 days and then delete them from the collection.

Comment: Do you store a timestamp/ or date at the documents level in the collection, to identify records older than 90 days?

Comment: yes in following format. createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-29T05:31:41.639Z")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to get 90th day from today. And apply that into `mongodump` using `--query=<json>` which accepts json documents as query params.

```js
const today = new Date();
const todayMillis = today.getTime();

/*90th past day from today*/
const nthDayfromToday = todayMillis - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.info(nthDayfromToday); //Lets say this is 1586450232676
```

Create a file `query.json` with contents- use the timestamp calculated above:

```
{ "createdAt": { "$lt": { "$date": 1586450232676 } } }
```

Run `mongodump` command:

```
mongodump --db <dbname> --collection <collection> --queryFile query.json
```

Comment: is converting into millisecond necessary, can't i just pass the date in dd-mm-yyyy format?

Comment: Milliseconds was only used simply to calculate 90th day from now easily. You can pass the date as dd-mm-yyyy format, if u have the 90th day before handy. Sure.